# Element in row space is mapped to column space when matrix is multiplied

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider a real matrix $A$ with $m$ rows and $n$ columns.

We know that row space and null space are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and also the common vector between them is only zero.

Similarly we can say that column space and null space of $A^{T}$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and also the common vector between them is only zero.

Now what I am interested is in the question

> if I take any element from row-space (say $u$), then can I say that $Au$ will be in column space ?

##### MY METHOD

Consider $r_{1}, r_{2}, ....., r_{m} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the rows of $A$. Then element in row space can be written as

$$
u = \Sigma_{i=1}^{m} c_{i}r_{i}
$$

I have computed $Au$ which will be in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. To check if its in null space of $A^{T}$, compute $A^{T}Au$ which will be

$$
A^{T}(Au) = \Sigma_{i=1}^{m} c_{i} (\Sigma_{j=1}^{m} (r_{j}^{T}r_{i}) r_{j})
= \Sigma_{i=1}^{m} (\Sigma_{j=1}^{m}c_{j} r_{j}^{T} r_{i})r_{i}
$$

Here, I am stuck. can I say that the above expression will be never be zero ?, If so how should I proceed to show that ?

##### EDIT

> if I take any element from row-space (say $u$), then can I say that $Au$ will be in column space ?

Of course, it will be in column space. I don't know what was I thinking. Sorry for the same.

One thing I can say that the scary expression above will never be zero vector.

Comment: For any $x\in\Bbb R^n$, $Ax$ is in the column space. You are messing up: You need *orthogonality* to the nullspace of $A^\top$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I feel really dumb now. What was I thinking for last 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific question I think it's trivial that $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{u} \in Col \mathbf{A} $. After all, for any vector $\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{A} \mathbf{v} \in Col \mathbf{A}$.

To show this: we can simply write the matrix in block form of its column vectors:

A = $\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}\mid & & \mid & & \mid \\ \mathbf{a}_1 & \cdots & \mathbf{a}_i & \cdots & \mathbf{a}_n \\ \mid & & \mid & & \mid\end{array}\right)$,
$\mathbf{u} = \left(\begin{array}{c}c_1\\c_2\\\vdots\\c_n
\end{array} \right)$

Then $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u} = c_1\mathbf{a_1}+\dots+c_n\mathbf{a_n} \in ColA$

Comment: Thanks for response. I have edited my question as well.